# How to connect React native with django rest api

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, api, django-rest-framework

I build a simple django rest api now i need to fetch data from it in frontend using React Native.
I can make a request to the api but the data is not coming from there.
I search about it a lot but didn't find any help
Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you using localhost or hosted api ?

Comment: @Kais localhost

Comment: try  local ip address instead of localhost

Comment: @Kais and how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

npm install axios

```
const axios = require('axios')

export const App = () =>{
const Your_Request = () =>{
const config= {
method:'get',
url:'YOUR URL',
}
axios(config).then((response)=>{
console.log('response',response)
}).catch((error)=>{
console.log('error',error)})
}
return (<View></View>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to see whether your API works correctly.
I can recommend you Postman (https://www.postman.com/) for that.
It's free, comes with an intuitive GUI, and allows you to make requests to your API, see the returned data, status codes, headers, and so on.

Once the API returns the data correctly, you'll need to fetch the data in the React application. For that you can either place `fetch()` requests in the respective lifecycle methods, although this will get burdensome quite quickly if you need authentication, etc..
Another option would be to build service infrastructure using React hooks to share state (such as API tokens) across the component tree.
Here's a post I wrote on how to do that: https://schneider-lukas.com/blog/react-connect-rest-api.